# How to search documents which are not in a particular geo area?

Tags: elasticsearch

I can't find any pieces of information on how to search a document which is not in a particular geo area.

For example, if I want to search for documents in an area of 200km around my GPS point (40, -70) I just have to do that :

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool" : {
            "must" : {
                "match_all" : {}
            },
            "filter" : {
                "geo_distance" : {
                    "distance" : "200km",
                    "pin.location" : {
                        "lat" : 40,
                        "lon" : -70
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But if I want to search for documents which **are not** in an area of 200km around my GPS point (40, -70). I have no clue how to do that.

Can you help me ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add `must_not` query like this

```
GET /my_locations1/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must_not": [
        {
          "geo_distance": {
            "distance": "200km",
            "pin.location": {
              "lat": 40,
              "lon": -70
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Hope this helps!!

Comment: Happy to help!!

Comment: Easier if you have only `bool/must_not` not nested inside a `bool/filter`, but that does the job for sure. `bool/must/match_all` is useless and can be removed.

Comment: @Val Correct. Edited